# Run timeError: cublas runtime error the GPU program failed to execute

Tags: python, gpu, torch, torchvision

I was running a python script in colab GPU when I got this error: “RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCBlas.cu:411”.

How can I solve this problem?

Pytorch version: 0.4.1 CUDA Version 10.0.130

Please let me know if any other details are required.